# Do multiple clients need multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

```
package General;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Server
{
    public static final int PORT = 7777;    
    protected static final int HEIGHT = 525;    
    protected static final int WIDTH = 1680;    
    private double y1 = 300;    
    private double y2 = 300;    
    private Scanner scan;    
    private PrintStream printStream;    
    private ServerThread one;    
    private ServerThread two;    

    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println( "THIS IS THE RIGHT SERVER" );
        new Server().runServer();
    }


    public void runServer() throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket( PORT );
        System.out.println( "Server up & ready for connection..." );
        while ( true )
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new ServerThread( socket ).start();
        }
    }


    public class ServerThread extends Thread
    {
        Socket socket;

        ServerThread( Socket socket )
        {
            this.socket = socket;
        }


        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                scan = new Scanner( socket.getInputStream() );
                printStream = new PrintStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
                System.out.println( "User " + scan.nextLine() + " has connected to the server." );
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for ( int j = 0; j > -1; j++ )
            {
                System.out.println( "nope" );
                printStream.println( "not running" );
                if ( scan.nextLine().equals( "started" ) )
                {
                    printStream.println( "go" );
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println( "nope2" );
            }

            try
            {
                System.out.println( "IM OUT" );
                printStream.flush();
                String message = null;
                while ( ( message = scan.nextLine() ) != null )
                {
                    if ( message.equals( "not started" ) || message.equals( "started" ) )
                    {
                        printStream.println( "lag" );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println( "Incoming client message: " + message );
                        String position = message.substring( 10 );
                        double positionDouble = Double.parseDouble( position );
                        String info = message.substring( 0, 8 );
                        if ( info.equals( "p1 y pos" ) )
                        {
                            y1 = positionDouble;
                            System.out.println( y1 );
                        }
                        else if ( info.equals( "p2 y pos" ) )
                        {
                            y2 = positionDouble;
                            System.out.println( y2 );
                        }
                        if ( info.equals( "p1 y pos" ) )
                        {
                            printStream.println( y2 );
                        }
                        else if ( info.equals( "p2 y pos" ) )
                        {
                            printStream.println( y1 );
                        }
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

package General;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BallMover extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();    
    Timer tm = new Timer( 1, this );    
    protected TextField tf;    
    protected Label score1;    
    protected int p1s = 0;    
    protected Label score2;    
    protected int p2s = 0;    
    protected static final int HEIGHT = 525;    
    protected static final int WIDTH = 1680;    
    protected double y1 = 300;    
    protected double y2 = 300;    
    protected double velY1 = 1.5;    
    protected double velY2 = 1.5;    
    protected double ballx = WIDTH / 2;    
    protected double bally = HEIGHT / 2;    
    protected double velBall = 1.2;    
    protected int ballAngle;    
    protected Font hehe;    
    protected static final int OFFSET = 0;    
    Socket socket;    
    PrintStream fileStream;    
    Scanner scan1;    

    public BallMover() throws IOException
    {
        socket = new Socket( "localhost", PORT );
        scan1 = new Scanner( socket.getInputStream() );
        fileStream = new PrintStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
        fileStream.println( name );

        hehe = new Font( "Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 25 );
        Rectangle instructions = new Rectangle( WIDTH / 3 - 10, OFFSET );
        instructions.setLocation( 10, 0 );
        Rectangle score1Pos = new Rectangle( WIDTH / 3, OFFSET );
        score1Pos.setLocation( WIDTH / 3, 0 );
        Rectangle score2Pos = new Rectangle( WIDTH / 3, OFFSET );
        score2Pos.setLocation( 2 * WIDTH / 3, 0 );
        Rectangle screen = new Rectangle( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        screen.setLocation( 0, 0 );

        tf = new TextField( "", 10 );
        tf.setBounds( new Rectangle( 5, 5 ) );
        tf.setFont( hehe );
        tf.setEditable( false );
        jf.add( tf );
        tf.addKeyListener( this );

        JLabel instruct = new JLabel( convertToMultiline(
            "Press: \n0 to restart \nq to change p1 padal direction \np to change p2 padal direction \ns to pause \ncy@ once you press 0"
                + "</html>" ) );
        instruct.setBounds( instructions );
        instruct.setFont( hehe );
        // jf.add( instruct );

        score1 = new Label( "Player 1 Score: " + p1s );
        score1.setBounds( score1Pos );
        score1.setFont( hehe );
        // jf.add( score1 );

        score2 = new Label( "Player 2 Score: " + p2s );
        score2.setBounds( score2Pos );
        score2.setFont( hehe );
        // jf.add( score2 );

        jf.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        this.setBounds( screen );
        jf.add( this );
        jf.setTitle( "BallMover1" );
        jf.setVisible( true );

        if ( Math.random() > .5 )
        {
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 315;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() ) + 45;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 135;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 180;
            }
        }
        String command;
        while ( true )
        {
            command = scan1.nextLine();
            fileStream.println( "not started" );
            System.out.println( command );
            if ( command.equals( "go" ) )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        fileStream.flush();
    }


    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent( g );
        g.setColor( Color.RED );
        g.fillRect( 30, (int)y1, 30, 200 );
        g.fillRect( WIDTH - 80, (int)y2, 30, 200 );
        g.fillOval( (int)ballx, (int)bally, 40, 40 );
        g.drawLine( 0, OFFSET, WIDTH, OFFSET );
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e )
    {
        char input = e.getKeyChar();
        if ( input == 's' )
        {
            if ( tm.isRunning() )
            {
                tm.stop();
            }
            else
            {
                tm.start();
            }
        }
        if ( input == 't' )
        {
            System.out.println( "ballx: " + ballx );
            System.out.println( "bally: " + bally );
            System.out.println( "delta x: " + velBall * Math.cos( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
            System.out.println( "delta y: " + velBall * Math.sin( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
            System.out.println( "ball angle: " + ballAngle );

        }
        if ( input == '0' )
        {
            velBall = 1.05;
            ballx = WIDTH / 2;
            bally = HEIGHT / 2;
            fileStream.println( "started" );
            tm.start();
        }
        if ( input == 'q' )
        {
            velY1 *= -1;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e )
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e )
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        System.out.println( "ballx: " + ballx );
        System.out.println( "bally: " + bally );
        System.out.println( "delta x: " + velBall * Math.cos( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
        System.out.println( "delta y: " + velBall * Math.sin( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
        System.out.println( "ball angle: " + ballAngle );
        System.out.println( "" );
        if ( y1 + 210 > HEIGHT || y1 <= OFFSET ) // p1 padal
        {
            if ( y1 <= OFFSET )
            {
                y1 = 5 + OFFSET;
            }
            velY1 *= -1;
        }
        if ( y2 + 210 > HEIGHT || y2 <= OFFSET )// p2 padal
        {
            if ( y2 <= OFFSET )
            {
                y2 = 5 + OFFSET;
            }
            velY2 *= -1;
        }
        y1 = y1 + velY1;
        y2 = y2 + velY2;
        if ( ballx < 70 && ballx > 40 && bally >= y1 && bally <= y1 + 200 ) // bounce
                                                                            // off
                                                                            // p1
        {
            System.out.println( "bdoink1" );
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 315;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() ) + 45;
            }
            velBall += .03;
        }

        if ( ballx > WIDTH - 100 && ballx < WIDTH - 70 && bally >= y2 && bally <= y2 + 200 ) // bounce
                                                                                             // off
                                                                                             // p2
        {
            System.out.println( "bdoink2" );
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 135;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 180;
            }
            velBall += .03;
        }

        if ( ballx < 0 ) // Player 2 Wins
        {
            p2s++;
            score2.setText( "Player 2 Score: " + p2s );
            tm.stop();
        }
        if ( ballx > WIDTH ) // Player 1 Wins
        {
            p1s++;
            score1.setText( "Player 1 Score: " + p1s );
            tm.stop();
        }
        if ( bally > HEIGHT - 50 || bally <= OFFSET ) // touches bottom or top
                                                      // wall
        {
            if ( bally <= OFFSET )
            {
                bally = 5 + OFFSET;
            }
            ballAngle *= -1;
        }
        ballx += velBall * Math.cos( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) );
        bally += velBall * Math.sin( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) );

        // send info to server
        System.out.println( "hi1" );
        fileStream.println( "p1 y pos: " + y1 );
        System.out.println( "hi2" );
        String work = scan1.nextLine();
        System.out.println( "hi3" );
        if ( work.equals( "lag" ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "hi4" );
        }
        else
        {
            y2 = Double.parseDouble( work );
        }
        System.out.println( "hi5" );
        repaint();

    }


    public static String convertToMultiline( String orig )
    {
        return "<html>" + orig.replaceAll( "\n", "<br>" );
    }

    // Client
    public static final int PORT = 7777;

    protected static final String name = "client1";


    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        new BallMover();
    }
}

package General;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class BallMover2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();    
    Timer tm = new Timer( 1, this );    
    protected TextField tf;    
    protected Label score1;    
    protected int p1s = 0;    
    protected Label score2;    
    protected int p2s = 0;    
    protected static final int HEIGHT = 525;    
    protected static final int WIDTH = 1680;    
    protected double y1 = 300;    
    protected double y2 = 300;    
    protected double velY1 = 1.5;    
    protected double velY2 = 1.5;    
    protected double ballx = WIDTH / 2;    
    protected double bally = HEIGHT / 2;    
    protected double velBall = 1.2;    
    protected int ballAngle;    
    protected Font hehe;    
    protected static final int OFFSET = 0;    
    Socket socket;    
    PrintStream fileStream;    
    Scanner scan1;    

    public BallMover2() throws IOException
    {
        socket = new Socket( "localhost", PORT );
        scan1 = new Scanner( socket.getInputStream() );
        fileStream = new PrintStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
        fileStream.println( name );

        hehe = new Font( "Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 25 );
        Rectangle instructions = new Rectangle( WIDTH / 3 - 10, OFFSET );
        instructions.setLocation( 10, 0 );
        Rectangle score1Pos = new Rectangle( WIDTH / 3, OFFSET );
        score1Pos.setLocation( WIDTH / 3, 0 );
        Rectangle score2Pos = new Rectangle( WIDTH / 3, OFFSET );
        score2Pos.setLocation( 2 * WIDTH / 3, 0 );
        Rectangle screen = new Rectangle( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        screen.setLocation( 0, 0 );

        tf = new TextField( "", 10 );
        tf.setBounds( new Rectangle( 5, 5 ) );
        tf.setFont( hehe );
        tf.setEditable( false );
        jf.add( tf );
        tf.addKeyListener( this );

        JLabel instruct = new JLabel( convertToMultiline(
            "Press: \n0 to restart \nq to change p1 padal direction \np to change p2 padal direction \ns to pause \ncy@ once you press 0"
                + "</html>" ) );
        instruct.setBounds( instructions );
        instruct.setFont( hehe );
        // jf.add( instruct );

        score1 = new Label( "Player 1 Score: " + p1s );
        score1.setBounds( score1Pos );
        score1.setFont( hehe );
        // jf.add( score1 );

        score2 = new Label( "Player 2 Score: " + p2s );
        score2.setBounds( score2Pos );
        score2.setFont( hehe );
        // jf.add( score2 );

        jf.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        this.setBounds( screen );
        jf.add( this );
        jf.setTitle( "BallMover2" );
        jf.setVisible( true );

        if ( Math.random() > .5 )
        {
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 315;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() ) + 45;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 135;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 180;
            }
        }
        String command;
        while ( true )
        {
            command = scan1.nextLine();
            fileStream.println( "not started" );
            System.out.println( command );
            if ( command.equals( "go" ) )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        fileStream.flush();
    }


    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent( g );
        g.setColor( Color.RED );
        g.fillRect( 30, (int)y1, 30, 200 );
        g.fillRect( WIDTH - 80, (int)y2, 30, 200 );
        g.fillOval( (int)ballx, (int)bally, 40, 40 );
        g.drawLine( 0, OFFSET, WIDTH, OFFSET );
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e )
    {
        char input = e.getKeyChar();
        if ( input == 's' )
        {
            if ( tm.isRunning() )
            {
                tm.stop();
            }
            else
            {
                tm.start();
            }
        }
        if ( input == 't' )
        {
            System.out.println( "ballx: " + ballx );
            System.out.println( "bally: " + bally );
            System.out.println( "delta x: " + velBall * Math.cos( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
            System.out.println( "delta y: " + velBall * Math.sin( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
            System.out.println( "ball angle: " + ballAngle );

        }
        if ( input == '0' )
        {
            velBall = 1.05;
            ballx = WIDTH / 2;
            bally = HEIGHT / 2;
            fileStream.println( "started" );
            tm.start();
        }
        if ( input == 'p' )
        {
            velY2 *= -1;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e )
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e )
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        System.out.println( "ballx: " + ballx );
        System.out.println( "bally: " + bally );
        System.out.println( "delta x: " + velBall * Math.cos( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
        System.out.println( "delta y: " + velBall * Math.sin( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) ) );
        System.out.println( "ball angle: " + ballAngle );
        System.out.println( "" );
        if ( y1 + 210 > HEIGHT || y1 <= OFFSET ) // p1 padal
        {
            if ( y1 <= OFFSET )
            {
                y1 = 5 + OFFSET;
            }
            velY1 *= -1;
        }
        if ( y2 + 210 > HEIGHT || y2 <= OFFSET )// p2 padal
        {
            if ( y2 <= OFFSET )
            {
                y2 = 5 + OFFSET;
            }
            velY2 *= -1;
        }
        y1 = y1 + velY1;
        y2 = y2 + velY2;
        if ( ballx < 70 && ballx > 40 && bally >= y1 && bally <= y1 + 200 ) // bounce
                                                                            // off
                                                                            // p1
        {
            System.out.println( "bdoink1" );
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 315;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() ) + 45;
            }
            velBall += .03;
        }

        if ( ballx > WIDTH - 100 && ballx < WIDTH - 70 && bally >= y2 && bally <= y2 + 200 ) // bounce
                                                                                             // off
                                                                                             // p2
        {
            System.out.println( "bdoink2" );
            if ( Math.random() > .5 )
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 135;
            }
            else
            {
                ballAngle = (int)( Math.random() * 45 ) + 180;
            }
            velBall += .03;
        }

        if ( ballx < 0 ) // Player 2 Wins
        {
            p2s++;
            score2.setText( "Player 2 Score: " + p2s );
            tm.stop();
        }
        if ( ballx > WIDTH ) // Player 1 Wins
        {
            p1s++;
            score1.setText( "Player 1 Score: " + p1s );
            tm.stop();
        }
        if ( bally > HEIGHT - 50 || bally <= OFFSET ) // touches bottom or top
                                                      // wall
        {
            if ( bally <= OFFSET )
            {
                bally = 5 + OFFSET;
            }
            ballAngle *= -1;
        }
        ballx += velBall * Math.cos( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) );
        bally += velBall * Math.sin( Math.toRadians( ballAngle ) );

        // send info to server
        System.out.println( "hi1" );
        fileStream.println( "p2 y pos: " + y2 );
        System.out.println( "hi2" );
        String work = scan1.nextLine();
        System.out.println( "hi3" );
        if ( work.equals( "lag" ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "hi4" );
        }
        else
        {
            y1 = Double.parseDouble( work );
        }
        System.out.println( "hi5" );
        repaint();

    }


    public static String convertToMultiline( String orig )
    {
        return "<html>" + orig.replaceAll( "\n", "<br>" );
    }

    // Client
    public static final int PORT = 7777;

    protected static final String name = "client2";


    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        new BallMover2();
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a pong game with 2 different clients. I made a server that would gather the information from the two pedals and frequently update the pedal locations. Whenever I run my code with 2 clients, the first client stops feeding information to the server. I was wondering if multiple clients need multiple threads. If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need `BallMover` and `BallMover2`? Aren't they just the same thing?

Comment: Sort answer is, yes. The client program should have it's own thread to read the response from the server. These operations can be blocking, making it imperative not to perform them on the Event Dispatching Thread.  You will need to devise a mechanism for synchronising the updates from the server with the EDT so you can reduce the risk of dirty read/writes, which can lead to graphical glitches. I recommend having a look at something like `SwingWorker`

Comment: ok thanks! I will look into that.